# put the image in the entire cell

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to show multiple tables in a web page with header and the image displayed inside the table cell.
To achieve that i have created one table and used `<div>` tag to assign the width and height of the `<td>.`

Please find the code below

```
<table width="100%" height="100%"><tr><td>
    <div style="position:absolute;border: 1px solid black;width:200px;height:200px";>
        <section>
            <header style="background: gray;width:198.5px;text-align: center">Header1</header>
        </section>
        <img style="display:block;" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://hearstcommerce.ca/customcontent/members/premium/sample.jpg" alt="tableDemo2" />
    </div></td>
    <td>
        <div  style="position:absolute;border: 1px solid black;width:200px;height:200px";>
            <section>
                <header style="background: gray;width:198.5px;text-align: center">Header2</header>
            </section><br><br>
            <br><br> <img style="display:block;" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://hearstcommerce.ca/customcontent/members/premium/sample.jpg" alt="" />
        </div></td>

    </tr></table>
```

I want to display that image in the whole cell of `<td>`. The header section should be displayed follwed by the image in the whole space. Please suggest what code do i need to add to make it work. Currently i could not able to set properly the image inside the border of the `<td>`. Or is there any good approach to achieve this. 
jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/4S6gR/103/
I want to achieve this using html/css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at you fiddle I think you meant you want the image to cover rest of the area in the cell other than header.

If so:

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4S6gR/106/)

Added a new div to cover the div, gave a height to the header `18px`, as was rendered by browser and then gave height of `182px` to the div containing image.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to display that image in the whole cell of td.

Forget img tags, there is a way easier way.

```
<td style="background-image:url('asd.jpg');">
```

Comment: Andras - But how can I show the header for the individual table displayed as shown in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4S6gR/103/

Comment: Header should be a table row, not a `<header>` tag inside your table cell. Put a new `tr` (and a `td` inside it) just after `table`, and do it there.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `th` instead of formatting inside `td` with `div` to create header, also you'll need to remove the height width from header

```css
.mytable{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.mytable header{
  background: gray;
  text-align: center;
}

.mytable img, header{
  width:200px;
}

.mytable td img{
  display:block; 
}
```

```html
<table class="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th>
      <section>
        <header>Header1</header>
      </section>
    </th>
    <th>
      <section>
        <header>Header2</header>
      </section>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://hearstcommerce.ca/customcontent/members/premium/sample.jpg" alt="" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://hearstcommerce.ca/customcontent/members/premium/sample.jpg" alt="" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I too like that way, but there should be a gap between each "td" as if they are different tables. Is there any way I can do that?I want Header1 and header2 with images displayed as if they are individual tables with some gap between them.

Comment: yeah that would require adding the 100% width to the table, and make the header width 200px, the img too, no need to set height because the image would scale, answer edited